# Coverage for C/Fortran Code

Tags: c, gcc, code-coverage, gfortran, gcov

I compile my code using gcc and gfortran. To generate coverage information, I used to add `--coverage` to both compiler flags (`FFLAGS` and `CFLAGS`), the compiler would generate `.gcno` files and upon running the program I would get `.gcda` files containing the coverage information.

After separating source and object directory (`src/*.c` and `out/obj/*.o`) the `gcda` files are not generated any more. At least I suppose it is due to that separation.

Is this fixable?

Comment: The `.gcda` file is generated in the directory where you originally compiled, not necessarily the directory where the executable resides, nor the directory from where you are launching. You could do a `find` to be sure.

Comment: I used find, they are neither next to the sources, nor in the working directory where I called make, nor next the object files

Comment: One thing you could try is use a system call trace tool (e.g. `strace` on linux) to see what your executable is doing. Search the logging output for occurrences of `gcda` or `gcno`, this may give a clue as to where it is looking or where it is writing.